# Yet another post about non-working SqlDependency

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know, I know there are many publications on this subject but none of them resolved my issue, which is as simple as exercise, nothing special. 
Basically, all of the Google results about not working `SqlDependency`, either here on SO or anywhere else follow the same approach. The last one I followed is located [here](http://blog.jsinh.in/monitoring-data-change-using-sqldependency-and-c/#.V9ZYsI9OIog). Here it goes:

Enable SQL Service Broker at the database level

```
ALTER DATABASE Test SET ENABLE_BROKER
```

The result is verified by:

```
SELECT Name, is_broker_enabled FROM sys.databases
```

This all looks as expected at mi side.

Next is the C# code. I created a console application and everything happens in the `static void Main(...`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (CanRequestNotifications())
        {
            var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDependency.Stop(cs);
            SqlDependency.Start(cs);

            using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(cs))
            using (var cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Name FROM [dbo].[Device]";
                cmd.Notification = null;

                var x = new SqlDependency();
                x.OnChange += X_OnChange;

                using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {

                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            SqlDependency.Stop(cs);

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access denied.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static bool CanRequestNotifications()
    {
        var result = false;

        var perm = new SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);

        try
        {
            perm.Demand();
            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static void X_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: ChangeDetected...", DateTime.Now);
    }
```

As you can see it isn't a matter of permissions as I check that prior starting the listener at all.

My configuration is like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;
            Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I read on multiple posts that the broker works fine with express editions of the MS SQL server; I tried both SQL Express 2014 and MSSQLLocalDB - same difference. I'm using VS 2015 and I'm issuing commands through its SQL Server Object Explorer (does that matter?) AFTER the program is started by hitting F5 - debug mode. All I get is a blank console; no errors, no anything. Then I execute the following statement from SSOE in VS but still nothing:

```
INSERT INTO Device(Name, MakerId, ComputerId) VALUES ('dfhj', 1, 1)

UPDATE [dbo].[Device] SET Name = 'dfhdfh' WHERE Id = 1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Been quite a while since I've used dependency myself (found it too unstable) - but are you sure you're not blocking the console app with your `Console.ReadLine();` ?

Comment: Common guys! Anyone?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen - Thanks for you thoughts, Allan. I have written many (test) applications like this and never had to worry about this. I'll check that out ...